# Term for "shocked because of silliness"

Tags: single-word-requests

If somebody doesn't know something very simple and you are shocked by their silliness, how can you express that with one word?

> I was ... because she didn't know president of Russia

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47682/discussion-on-question-by-jon-snows-papa-term-for-shocked-because-of-silliness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am shocked – shocked! – that nobody has suggested ***flabbergasted*** 
(the past participle of ***flabbergast***):

> [the Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/flabbergast):
>
>   to shock someone,
>     usually by telling that person something they were not expecting:
>   *He was flabbergasted when we told him how cheap it was.*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flabbergast):
>
>   to overwhelm with shock, surprise, or wonder : dumbfound

So see also ***overwhelmed*** and ***dumbfounded***.

Comment: "I'm shocked, shocked to find that gambling is going on in here". Capt. Renault to Rick Blane, Casablanca. Undoubtedly he was also flabbergasted. In fact, I'd go so far as to suggest that his flabber had never been so gasted!

Comment: @PeterPoint: I was hoping *somebody* would catch the reference.

Comment: I am shocked—shocked!—that you would thus deny [Mick’s comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352720/term-for-shocked-because-of-silliness#comment817810_352720). ;-)

Comment: @Peter Point But what does flabber mean?  It sounds somewhat like flubber or blubber, and Capt. Renault was dapper -- he didn't have any flabber to be gasted.

Comment: @ab2  Quite so! Capt. Renault was so dapper that I don't think I ever saw a French kepi worn at such a jaunty angle! I better fess up: I filched the flabber gag from none other than Ken Dodd, a comic genius beloved by the Brits.

Comment: @PeterPoint:  "filch" — now there's another word I don't hear every day.

Comment: @Scott  "Filch" It was the late Dapper Don's favorite word, so much more euphemistic is his line of work, don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

Hang on a mo!

What about, *I was thoroughly* **discombobulated** *because she didn't know that the president of Russia is Vladimir Putin.*

**discombobulate:** (verb) INFORMAL, MAINLY HUMOROUS -- to confuse someone or make someone feel uncomfortable (Cambridge Dictionary)

In the alternative, what about, *I was totally* **bamboozled** *by my sister being unable to remember where she had parked our car in the shopping mall*

**bamboozle:** To confuse, frustrate, or throw off thoroughly or completely. (M-W)

Comment: +1 for hexa-syllabification (and for reminding me of a word I haven't heard since Ingrid Bergman was alive).

Answer (score 2):

How about *astonished*, *astounded*, or *stunned*?

From The Free Dictionary:

> [*astonished*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/astonished): filled
> with the emotional impact of overwhelming surprise or shock.
>
> Synonyms: amazed, surprised, staggered, bewildered, astounded, dazed,
> stunned, confounded, perplexed, gobsmacked (informal), dumbfounded,
> flabbergasted (informal), stupefied

Your example:

> I was *astonished* she didn't know president of Russia.

Of the synonyms, perhaps *astounded* or *stunned* best fits your question, depending on exactly what you wish to convey.

From The Free Dictionary:

> [*astounded*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/astounded): overwhelmed
> with amazement and wonder; bewildered
>
> [*stunned*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stunned): shocked or
> astounded

Your example:

> I was *astounded* she didn't know president of Russia.
>
> I was *stunned* she didn't know president of Russia.

Lots of good possibilities, some of which have already been mentioned by other users. *Shocked* itself was fine.